# scikit-learn AgglomerativeClustering and connectivity

Tags: scikit-learn, connectivity, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to use AgglomerativeClustering from scikit-learn to cluster points on a place. Points are defined by coordinates (X,Y) stored in _XY.

Cluster are limited to a few neighbours through the connectivity matrix defined by 
`C = kneighbors_graph(_XY, n_neighbors = 20)`.

I want some points not be part of the same cluster, even if they are neighbours, so I modified the connectivity matrix to put 0 between these points.

The algorithm runs smoothly but, at the end, some clusters contain points that should not be together, i.e. some couple for which I imposed _C = 0.

From the children, I can see that the problem arises when a cluster of two points (i, j) is already formed and that k joins (i,j) even if _C[i,k]=0.

So I was wondering how the connectivity constraint is propagated when the size of some clusters is larger than 2, _C being not defined in that case.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

So what seems to be happening in your case is that despite your active disconnection of point you do not want to have in one cluster, these points are still part of the same connected component and the data associated to them still imply that they should be connected to the same cluster from a certain level up.

In general, `AgglomerativeClustering` works as follows: At the beginning, all data points are separate clusters. Then, at each iteration, two adjacent clusters are merged, such that the overall increase in discrepancy with the original data is minimal if we compare the original data with cluster means in L2 distance.

Hence, although you sever the direct link between two nodes, they can be clustered together one level higher by an intermediate node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Let's see if I got it write.

Suppose that C[i,j] = 1, C[j,k] = 1 and C[i,k] = 0. i and k can not be linked. At the first step, i and j are linked. Then k could be linked to the cluster (i,j). I thought that, because C[i,k] = 0, k could not be joined. But, in fact, because C[j,k] = 1, there is possible a connection between (i,j) and k. It is like defining C[(i,j),k] = max(C[i,k], C[j,k]).

Comment: Please don't hesitate to ask questions - it is not straightforward to explain the mechanism in few words

Comment: Exactly -- they are just linked via an intermediary. I do not think that it is possible to prohibit these clusters from forming if the data are sufficiently similar. Unless you disconnect the components fully, of course. But in that case, the agglomerator sometimes even re-links disconnected components.